# Maximizing a function with constant sum of parameters

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

For integers $x_1,\cdots, x_n$, I want to  maximize $F(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$ so that $\sum_i x_i \le K$ where $K$ is a positive integer. It is a very special case of *Integer Programming*. Is that easy to solve for any non-trivial class of functions? For instance when $F(\cdot)$ is linear or concave?

**Edit**

For linear $F(\cdot)$, I noticed that the answer would be to assign the whole $K$ to the $x_i$ with maximum weight.

Comment: The maximum also occurs at a vertex (i.e. the whole $K$ on a single $x_i$) if $F$ is *convex*, but that may not be interesting to you. I wonder if something useful can be said if $F$ is separable into $F_1(x_1)+\dots+F_n(x_n)$.

Comment: If $K=2$, the convex function $F(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-2)^2 + (x_2-2)^2$ is maximized at $x=0$ if the $x_i$ are required to be nonnegative and is unbounded if the $x_i$ are unrestricted in sign. Setting $x_i=K$ for either $i$ is not optimal.